# Reverse proxy for Lektor CMS

Tags: lektor

The Lektor server is running on port 5000 on localhost. I want to make it accessible via an Apache URL at http://myhost.org/lektor. Therefore, I've tried the httpd config snippet

```
ProxyPass        /lektor http://127.0.0.1:5000
ProxyPassReverse /lektor http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

The HTML for the welcome page is found, but the static pages referenced there (e.g., http://myhost.org/static/style.css) are not. How can I make the changed URL known to Lektor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The development server is not intended to be used for production.  The production deployments are based on entirely static content and will resolve static assets correctly if you use the `|url` filter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I want to do is not production deployment, but support some basic editorial workflow - one editor makes changes, another does the proofreading ,- before anything is deployed publicly, and without differing formal access rights involved.

Answer (score 2):

I had success with just slightly different syntax:

```
ProxyPass / "http://localhost:5000/"
ProxyPassReverse / "http://localhost:5000/"
```

Seems the trailing slash is needed.  I'm not sure whether you need the actual name "localhost" in there, but that's what worked for me.

I did the following additional items with my setup, and it's rather slick:

- Set up Lektor on an internal private-ip webserver
- Set up two virtual hosts, for example lektor-web-dev.my.domain and lektor-web.my.domain
- Set up self-signed certificates on the -dev domain, and used the above ProxyPass items in its vhost config (Apache)
- Set up basic authentication on the -dev domain, so there's at least a basic level of authentication
- Set up rsync deploy to loop back to localhost using an SSH keypair, and copy the output files to lektor-web.my.domain's webroot

Now, lektor-web.my.domain is still on a private webserver without certificates.  However, on my public-facing webserver, I SSL terminate and proxy through to lektor-web.my.domain.  I get the certificate with letsencrypt.

This is expandable to any number of websites.  Keep the Lektor admins running using supervisor or some other process management system.  Use 'lektor server -p portnum' to pick a different port for each site's admin.  You can do group-based access to various admins using HTTP basic authentication along with an htpasswd and htgroup file.

Comment: To be clear, the author's point about the admin not being for production use stands--one doesn't want to host a site on this.  However, I definitely reap the benefits from hosting multiple Lektor servers on a Linux box, with properly protected access.

Just be sure to host it in private IP space, to SSL encrypt it, to protect access with user/group membership.  I require any use of these hosted Lektor servers to be through a VPN if not on my private LAN.

Then set it up to deploy the site to different virtual hosts for public viewing.

Comment: To be clear, you wouldn't host the public-facing website this way, rather, it is a way to keep a farm of protected Lektor servers running behind VPN/SSL/user auth for editorial use.